# Is changing Data Type causing some problems on Google Cloud?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Ok, Now, I deploy my app with this code.

```
Entity entity=new Entity("StructureObject", structureObjectParentKey);
String description=getData();
entity.setUnindexedProperty("Description",description);
datastore.put(entity);
```

Then I insert some data (Ex: "I love you", "ok") into my app & I can get data without any problem.

Now, at this moment, in my `Description` property of `StructureObject` kind, I have 2 entries: "*I love you*", "*ok*" and I can access them (`retrieve?id=1` or `retrieve?id=2`).

Now, I change my code in Eclipse to:

```
Entity entity=new Entity("StructureObject", structureObjectParentKey);
Text description=getData();
entity.setUnindexedProperty("Description",description);
datastore.put(entity);
```

Now I insert 2 more entries "*I love you2*", "*ok2*". Now, a strange thing happened. I can access 2 new entries "*I love you2*", "*ok2*" (`retrieve?id=3` and `retrieve?id=4`), but I can not retrieve (`retrieve?id=1` or `retrieve?id=2`).

Here is the Error

```
    Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text
    at com.fluent.StructureObject.getStructureObject(StructureObject.java:138)
    at com.fluent.StructureServlet.doGet(StructureServlet.java:16)
```

**Is changing DataType causing some problems on Google Cloud?**

Comment: when entering the link "**retrieve?id=3**" it should show "*I love you2*", but after change the code when entering the link "**retrieve?id=2**", it shows error!

Comment: Could you paste what the error says?

Comment: It is in Google Cloud, I don't know how to see it

Comment: You should be able to access the cloud logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs?project=myappname
where myappname is the name of your cloud project. (You may need to log into the google account that owns the project).

Comment: Got it, seem I got Datatype problem!

Comment: You don't show what your `retrieve` handler does, but you have *put* a `String` property and are trying to cast it to a `Text`, which is a different class altogether.  My answer to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403697/how-to-retrieve-text-type-from-datastore-google-cloud) should help.

Comment: @tx802, is there any way to change the datatype manually on Google cloud. I don't want to delete data & reinserting data again

Comment: @Tum You can read the affected entities, remove the `String` properties and re-save them with `Text`.  Or you could use [Objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify) which will handle the two types seamlessly. (Remember also, `Text` properties will not be indexed).

Comment: @tx802, but there is no text data type in Google Cloud. Only see String Type when Inserting Java Text & String into Datastore

Comment: There is a 'Text' property, com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text, which differs from String in that it can store up to 1MB and is not indexed. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.