# How to retrieve Text type from Datastore Google Cloud?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Ok, These are all basic questions but there are not many answers found on the Internet.

OK, Now, I insert into Datastore using this Java code

```
Text descriptionText=new Text(description);
structureEntity.setUnindexedProperty("Description",descriptionText);
```

Anh here is the retrieving code:

```
Text description=(Text)structureObjectEntity.getProperty("Description");\
System.out.println(description);
```

Now, let say, I insert "`We should arrive before dark.<br>I should have finished the book by Friday. <br>The roads should be less crowded today.<br><br>Source: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/should?q=should`" into Datastore

But when retrieving data, the `System.out.println(description);` return `<Text: We should arrive before dark.<br>I should have finished the book by Fr...>` (some data got lost & there is `<Text:` at the head of the data & `...` at the tail of the data) & that messed up everything.

So, **How to retrieve Text type from Datastore Google Cloud?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the `getValue()` method.  If you pass the `Text` object to `println()` it will call the `toString()` method.  [Here are the Javadocs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text)

Comment: Also, If I missed inserting String data into Datastore at the beginning, but now changed to Text. You can see my other question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401446/is-changing-data-type-causing-some-problems-on-google-cloud?noredirect=1#comment60424290_36401446.